# how to package wear app

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I have gotten signed my wear app , as per said by developer site . and also I have imported that into my
raw folder with the name of "wear_release.apk"

I have created xml folder in res in the device app and also I have put the necessary with correct package name these are as follows

```
 <wearableApp package="wearable.app.package.name">
  <versionCode>1</versionCode>
  <versionName>1.0</versionName>
  <rawPathResId>wearable_app</rawPathResId> 
</wearableApp>
```

but when i put meta tag into the manifest file of the handheld device and try to build and sign the mobile app I got error

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
                 android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>`
```

i got error

> Error:(52, 13) Execution failed for task
>   ':mobile:processReleaseManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.wearable.beta.app@resource
> >     value=(@xml/wear_release_desc) from AndroidManifest.xml:52:13     is also
> >     present at AndroidManifest.xml:5:20
> >     value=(@xml/android_wear_micro_apk)   Suggestion: add
> >     'tools:replace="android:resource"' to  element at
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:50:9 to override

can any one tell me what is the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your apk's name is wear_release.apk, but the name you write in the wearable_app_desc is wearable_app, you must write the same name, wear_release

Answer (score 0):

If you use gradle, and it seems to be the case, you don't need to put your apk into the raw folder, from memory it's only for Eclipse and ADT. When using gadle, just put the line `wearApp project(':nameOfYourWearProject')` as a child element of `dependencies` in the file "build.gradle" of your handheld project.

Comment: I have done that also , in my studio I have build with that and my package name and my code is same also i have added permissions on both side . but when I install app on mobile and  try to apply watchface on my wear it never gets apply. my watch is of Samsung galaxy gear model SAM-V700

Comment: Is your wear app successfully installed on your watch ?

Comment: No and that is a point How to make it confirm that my app is also installing on the wear ?

Comment: and I am using android studio\

Comment: If you are using the debug mode, you can choose on Android Studio to install the apk on the Wearable. Just build your Wearable project and select the watch when AS is asking you which device you want to install it on. You need to enable Debugging over bluetooth and follow the instructions here : http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html If you are using the release flavor, just make sure you sign both apk with the same key and when installing the app on your handheld it will be installed on your watch.

Comment: thanks for replying @snow but I have figured out the problem and that is the sdk version of device is 17 and AS needs min 20 to install the wear app. So its mean I have to install the updates, But the problem If I would update my watch it will go to tizen , and I am not confirmed that after updating , will watch be able to install my app , as it is made in android using google api